# How to read records that matches multiple values in the same field?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to read records that match multiple values in the same field.
Example table : A

```
UserID  License
1   DOG
1   CAT
1   FISH
2   DOG
2   CAT
3   FISH
4   CAT
4   DOG
4   FISH
5   CAT
5   FISH
```

How can I pull the UserIDs that have all three Licenses DOG, CAT and FISH ?

I am not sure how I could use INNER JOIN here since there are no two tables.
What is the best approach here ?

Thank you 
PG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't even think about unnecessary** `INNER JOIN` for this simple task. Let's do it using [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
SELECT UserID FROM A WHERE License IN('DOG','CAT','FISH');
```

**N.B** But still I'm little bit confused with this line though How can I pull the UserIDs that have **all** three Licenses DOG, CAT and FISH ?

**Edited:** This eliminate my confusion about *all*, try like this way and grab only the UserId from the output.

```
SELECT UserID,count(*) as lnt FROM A WHERE 
  License IN('DOG','CAT','FISH') 
group by UserId having lnt = 3;
```

**Output:**

```
UserID  lnt
  1     3
  4     3
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e563ef/4

Comment: Just want to elaborate `Join : combines columns from one or more tables in a relational database`. +1 for fast typing.. :D

Comment: This would retrieve a `UserID` that has ANY dog, cat, or fish license, not only users that have ALL three. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e563ef/1 `IN` is basically a shortened syntax of `OR`

Comment: @fyrye thanks mate, you've cleared my confustion about  the *all* three. I've modified my answer to return only ids that has **all** three value like DOG, CAT, FISH, Thnkx. again.

Comment: Great . . thanks for the help. I never thought of 'IN'

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case when...` in your sql, like this:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(CASE WHEN License IN ("DOG", "CAT", "FISH") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LICENSE_COUNT
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING LICENSE_COUNT = 3
```

Comment: Please correct the syntax error. You might try creating a fiddle at e.g. sqlfiddle.com or dbfiddle.uk to verify that the code you post will run, and produce the results you expect. Thanks.

Comment: I have verified my sql on my computer and it worked!!

Comment: My mistake - I didn't realize MySQL accepted double-quotes as string delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

"How can I pull the UserIDs that have all three Licenses DOG, CAT and FISH ?"

Like this:

```
SELECT USERID, COUNT(*) AS LICENSE_COUNT
  FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
  GROUP BY USERID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1405be00bc0f456e7f2ed3ca400f4fa)

Comment: This would provide false positives if a license other than dog, cat or fish were added or already in the database.

Comment: That's a different question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

try to like this:

```
select userid 
from example_table 
WHERE License IN('DOG','CAT','FISH') group by user_id having count(distinct License)=3
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers stated, it is better to use IN operator instead of Join. You can get the desired result even without using group by or HAVING. Try this

```
Select DISTINCT(UserId) from A 
Where UserID IN(Select userId from A where License='DOG') 
AND UserID IN (Select UserId from A where License='CAT') 
AND UserID IN (Select UserId from A where License='FISH')
```